# Custom navigation with Liknlist web part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm using a standard link list web part. What I want to achieve is before my users click on the link a pop-up javascript warning box will display, stating that they are leaving the domain. In regular anchor tag I would preceed the URL with javascript:ShowWarning('http://www.youtube.com');.

I've search the AllLinks table in the database but did not find the links was looking for.

Where or how are these stored?

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, editing the SharePoint database directly is a really bad idea. You shouldn't do it unless you really, really know what you are doing, and even then you will probably break the system.

Secondly, any change made in the data will be what shows up in the editor, and I don't think the editor supports links that don't start with "http://".

A better approach is to use jquery to add the popup behaviour to the links when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the word. I've been working with SQL database for a long time, and I don't know jquery. So where do I start?